# Enabling virtio_blk_device for qemu

Tags: linux, qemu

I am using `qemu 2.2.0` to emulate x86 Linux guest on x86 Linux host.
I want to use the existing dataplane mechanism in QEMU (implemented using virtqueue & IOThreads )for achieving parallel R/W operations in my device.
It requires enabling virtio-blk-device & verifying concurrency in existing framework before implementing the same for my device.
I use the following commnand to enable virtio block device & boot qemu:

```
./qemu-system-x86_64_exe -m 2048 -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -usbdevice tablet -enable-kvm -drive if=none,id=drive1,file=debian_wheezy_i386_desktop.raw -object iothread,id=iothread2 -device virtio-blk-device,id=drv0,drive=drive1,iothread=iothread2 -smp 8
 This command executes with error: 
No 'virtio-bus' found for device 'virtio-blk-device' .
```

However, querying this device using " `./qemu-system-x86_64_exe -device help`" displays following info for virtio-blk-device:
name `virtio-blk-device`, bus `virtio-bus`.

Is there something amiss in my Command line options ?

Comment: Did you compiled qemu yourself ?If yes,  during the configure step did you enabled the virtio block ?

Comment: Yes ..I did.. if I see all the avaiable device in QEMU, I can see virtio-blk-device.  Is there any command to see all the buses currently enabled in system ?

Comment: When you do ./configure -h it should show you what options are present.. you should be able to see all available buses..

Answer (score 1):

`virtio-blk-device` is a VirtIO device that relies solely on memory-mapped IO (MMIO) and not on the PCI-bus. This does not work with Qemu's default machine type `pc-i440fx-X.Y`, or at least not out of the box.

You can use the machine type `microvm` (https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/i386/microvm.html), a minimalistic machine type without PCI and ACPI. To do so you would add `-machine microvm` to your Qemu commandline. Then `virtio-blk-device` and also `virtio-net-device` should work out of the box. You won't be able to use any devices that rely on PCI however.

As already suggested switching to the PCI-variants is probably the best option in most usecases. As for the error message that no PCI bus is found, maybe your Qemu build defaults to some very weird machine type. Try setting it specifically to `-machine pc`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and couldn't find informations for virtio-blk-device.
I swichted to virtio-blk-pci instead.

Comment: When I switched `-device` to `-pci` I get a new error of `No 'PCI' bus found for device`.